# Biopython for similarity matrix - looking for better performance

Tags: python, numpy, biopython

I want to calculate the similarity between a input sequence and a short fragment from the sequence. The outcome is a similarity matrix with each position being the score of the alignment.
It works, but is unfortunately slow. How could I implement the loop more efficiently in python and numpy? I am also thinking to use MPI, but multithreading or even better an internal numpy solution would be beneficial. Below is the code.

```
from Bio import pairwise2
import numpy

....

similarityMatrix = numpy.zeros(shape=(sequenceLength-fragmentLength,sequenceLength-fragmentLength))

for i in xrange(sequenceLength-fragmentLength):
    currentFragment = sequence[i:i+fragmentLength]

    for j in xrange(i,sequenceLength-fragmentLength):
        aFragment = sequence[j:j+fragmentLength]

        alns = pairwise2.align.globalds(aFragment, currentFragment, matrix, gap_open, gap_extend)

        bestHit = alns[0]
        score = bestHit[2]

        similarityMatrix[i,j] = float(score)
        similarityMatrix[j,i] = float(score)
```

Comment: What you are really doing is local alignment. For this you need the Smith-Waterman algorithm.

Comment: I would like to help, but I didn't understand what you are trying to achieve. Anyways, your code can benefit a lot of using pypy. Try it, you don't need to change anything. If you want some more help, please update your question with an example.

Comment: @wasserfeder. Yes, it is local alignment and I am interested in the matrix, not the alignment outcome. But in Biopython I didnt the function that returns the matrix - hence I thought to generate it myself...

Answer (score 2):

First I would try to compute only half of the diagonal, **starting** the inner loop in the `i` point and avoiding the calculation of previous alignments:

```
for i in range(full_size - frag_size):
    curr_frag = seq[i:i + frag_size]

    # ADD THIS ----vvvvv------------vvv
    for j in range(i + 1, full_size + 1 - frag_size):
        match_frag = seq[j:j + frag_size]
        # Do the following calculation here
```

Another thing could be to do only the calculation of the score, but I feel this is too minor improvement. Do the profiling:

```
score = pairwise2.align.globalds(aFragment,
                                 currentFragment,
                                 matrix,
                                 gap_open,
                                 gap_extend,
                                 score_only=True)  # <= ADD THIS
```

---

**Vectorize** from `numpy`. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

> Define a vectorized function which takes a nested sequence of objects or numpy arrays as inputs and returns a numpy array as output.

```
def chop(sequence, frag_size):
    for i in range(full_size - frag_size):
        yield sequence[i + 1:i + 1 + frag_size]

def pairwise(seq1, seq2):
    return pairwise2.align.globalds(
        seq1, seq2, MATRIX, -2, -1, score_only=True)

query = numpy.array([x for x in chop(seq, frag_size)])
subject =  numpy.array([x for x in chop(seq, frag_size)])

vfunc = numpy.vectorize(pairwise)

results = []
for i in subject:
    results.append(vfunc(i, query))
```

But you will gain no performance. As they say:

> The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

Comment: Yes, I changed the code to nxn/2 after posting the original question. I'll look into the globalds function, thanks for the tip.

Comment: I'm adding the `numpy` you asked for, but it's useless except for "Beautiful is better than ugly." while saving some for loops.